# Calculate the sum of array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new at javascript and am trying to finish up a test. So far I've done ok, but I can't seem to get right the three last things:
- it should return the sum with one number array
- it should return zero if all elements are zero
- it should return the sum when passed array of numbers

```
const numbers = [6, 12, 1, 18, 13, 16, 2, 1, 8, 10];

function sumNumbers(arr){
  if (arr === undefined || arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  array.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return the result of *reduce*, there is no array named *array*, should be *arr*:

```
return arr.reduce(function(a, b){
```

```js
const numbers = [6, 12, 1, 18, 13, 16, 2, 1, 8, 10];

function sumNumbers(arr){
  if (arr === undefined || arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}, 0);
}
console.log(sumNumbers(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of `return` and take the same variable `array`.

```js
function sumNumbers(array) {
  if (array === undefined || array.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
}

const numbers = [6, 12, 1, 18, 13, 16, 2, 1, 8, 10];

console.log(sumNumbers(numbers));
```

A shorter approach uses a default array and return just the result of `reduce`.

```js
function sumNumbers(array) {
    return (array || []).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}

const numbers = [6, 12, 1, 18, 13, 16, 2, 1, 8, 10];

console.log(sumNumbers(numbers));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't see that.